# What model is the "Future Terminator" in The Terminator?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

During one of the flashbacks that Kyle Reese has in The Terminator we get to see a Terminator attack a human settlement.

Based on its realistic appearance this Terminator appears to be a 800 series, but different than the model 101 that is hunting Sarah. IMDB credits [Franco Columbu](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0173372/?ref_=tt_cl_t12) in the role, and lists the part as just "Future Terminator."

Is there any information on what model this Terminator is?

[image]

Comment: Bad take on James Cameron's part, you were not suppose to be able to still shot this. They probably should have hid its face. When you look at it from far, it was suppose to resemble Arnold. I know when I saw it, I did not look to still shot it and care. Now that you did, I appreciate it.

Comment: @WantingAnswers - no, only the 101 looks like Arnold. The 102 looks like someone else, the 103 like a different guy, and so on. When Cameron said that there are hundreds of these things coming off an assembly line and they all looked like Arnold, he was referring to the 101 by itself. Heck, if all the Terminators looked the same, they'd be pretty easy to spot.

Comment: @Omegacron: Easiest thing to at least make faces different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Terminator Wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Future_Terminator) says it is a Series 800 but its model number is unknown. It may be considered a T-808 or T-810 based on the fact that Franco's likeness was used for the images of the T-808 and T-810 in The Terminator Collectible Card Game.

Comment: Null: It would be a different model number, not a series #. If you state that it should be a different model number, then you should stick with it. Your last two sentences  contradict what you had previous written. 

Series would mean that actual series. The 8 and 10 would be model. Then it would go to the next series 801. etc. 

Basically Skynet made 800 Terminators of differing series and this is model whatever. Arnold is a series 800, but it was modeled 101. Skynet pretty much had a diverse amount of facial features to attach to 100 other models before the Arnold one.

Answer (score 1):

The Terminator wiki assumes it is a T-800 which is plausible, but we know Arnold is a T-800 model 101, so we can assume Franco would be a T-800 model 10? 106, 107, 112? The list of templates could be endless.